# Why is my sql query returning an empty table?

Tags: python, sqlite, flask

I'm pretty new to python and to flask, and I've been trying to make a program where people can store their receipts. I've got three tables, users, receipts, and user_receipts. im trying to make a page where it lists all the receipts from the user thats logged in, however im just getting blank tables every time, even if the user has entered a receipt.

```
def list():

    global user_id


    con = sql.connect("database.db")
    con.row_factory = sql.Row

    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute("select * from receipts WHERE receiptID = (select receipt_id from user_receipts WHERE user_id =?)", (user_id,))

    rows = cur.fetchall();
    return render_template("view_receipts.html",rows = rows)
```

I know that my methods for naming my variables are not consistent, however I'm aware of which variables belong to which table and I am 100 percent sure they are right.
Im just not sure why its giving me empty tables every time.

Comment: Did you execute the query in CLI just to verify there's no problem with the query itself?

Comment: Is your user_id set as well?

Comment: I did execute the query in the sql command thingy as well and it worked there, so im not sure what the issue is. Evem when i change the user id to specifically one that i know has made purchases nothing comes up

Comment: Not the solution, but you should use debugger to find out the exact cause of the problem. You IDEs or even simple print() statements to figure out the point of failure. More info will surely help.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend first checking if it is a problem with flask or SQLite first by doing a simple print statement for debugging.

If its a problem with SQLite I recommend to try to modify the variable names and see if there was an error while making the table

if all else fails try to move to something like sqlalchemy so you can get a more reliable database.